# What is the command to remove git?

Tags: powershell

I tried to remove git from my subfolder react project in my parent folder MERN project..

I tried the command `rm -rf .git` in my react/frontend folder but it display :

```
Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 
'rf'.
```

Comment: Windows unfortunately aliases `rm` to its not entirely equivalent `Remove-Item` command (as the error suggests). You'll need to look into the `Remove-Item` equivalent syntax. As a manual workaround though, you can always just go into `explorer` and delete is like you would any other directory.

Comment: Note that you're not "removing Git", you're "removing the repository". Git is the suite of tools; the repository is the database containing all the commits.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using windows powershell. if that's the case, use the equivalent of "rm -rf" for powershell which would be: "rm -r -fo"